# Java; Generic Observer/Observable - is this as messy as I think?

Tags: java, mvc, generics

I have recently had a whole load of help trying to roll my own *loosely-coupled* Observable/Observer paradigm, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498315/loosely-coupled-observer-pattern

To keep things simple and to aid in my understanding of the basic concepts, I asked about a specific implementation of Dog (Observable) vs Owner (Observer).

I am now trying to change that implementation into something more generic, so that I can create different types of Observers/Observables/Events for an actual application I intend to write.

I have something working now but I get the feeling that what I've got is going to cause me problems further down the line as my application grows.

I'd very much appreciate comments and suggestions on the following code, if indeed it is bad in some way (I think the Source class looks particularly nasty!). I'd like to know if this code is improvable, and if it is, how?

```
// --- An event has a type (what happened?)

public enum EventType {

    CREATE,
    UPDATE,
    DELETE
}

// --- Event contains what happened and the Observable that notified

public class Event<SourceType> {

    private SourceType source;
    private EventType type;

    public SourceType getSource() { return source; }
    public EventType getType() { return type; }

    public Event(SourceType _source, EventType _type) {

        source = _source;
        type = _type;
    }
}

// --- Listener interface

public interface IListener<SourceType> {

    public void onEvent(Event<SourceType> _event);
}

// --- Implementation of that interface - this is a custom listener that deals with Persons.
// --- It looks like I'll need a new *Something*Listener for each additional Observer I want to observe.

public class PersonListener implements IListener<Person> {

    public void onEvent(Event<Person> _event) {

        System.out.println("EVENT: " + _event.getSource().getName());
        // Would probably have a switch/case statement here to check the Event type (what happened?)
    }
}

// --- A generic Observable

public class Source<ListenerType extends IListener<SourceType>, SourceType> {

    private Set<ListenerType> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<ListenerType>();

    public void addListener(ListenerType _listener) { listeners.add(_listener); }

    public void fireEvent(Event<SourceType> _event) {

        for(ListenerType listener : listeners) {

            listener.onEvent(_event);
        }
    }
}

// --- A person who is observable (ill be subclassing this later into i.e Driver, Client, Receptionist)

public class Person extends Source<PersonListener, Person> {

    private String name;

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String _name) {

        name = _name;
        fireEvent(new Event<Person>(this, EventType.UPDATE));
    }

    public Person(String _name) {

        setName(_name);
    }
}

// --- Entry point

public class Boot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person = new Person("Unnamed");
        PersonListener listener = new PersonListener();

        person.addListener(listener);

        person.setName("Dave");
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I'd like to point out that one of my main aims here is to have a decoupled Observer/Observable pattern for use with a MVC-pattern.

I intend to subclass these 'generic' classes (or perhaps use them within other classes instead, composition style). At some point I will have a series of 'Views' that will observe 'Models', but the Models will not 'care' or 'know about' about the Views. Wikipedia shows a circular MVC diagram which I am aiming to follow:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

As the Source class right now needs a ListenerType (i.e a View) generic to be passed to it on instantiation; I am not sure if I have achieved de-coupling yet. Having said that, it is a *generic* value so perhaps this is already as abstract as it can be.

I am also having to pass a SourceType generic to the Listener to it can send that to any Events it fires. At the moment its the best I can do but I have a suspicion it could be done a better, more abstract way.

**Edit #2**

Thanks Amir for your kind help; here is the code in its current state:

```
public enum EventType {

    CREATE,
    UPDATE,
    DELETE
}

public class Event<SourceType> {

    private SourceType source;
    private EventType type;

    public SourceType getSource() { return source; }
    public EventType getType() { return type; }

    public Event(SourceType _source, EventType _type) {

        source = _source;
        type = _type;
    }
}

public interface IListener {

    public void onEvent(Event<? extends ISource> _event);
}

public interface ISource {

    public void addListener(IListener _listener);
    public void fireEvent(EventType _eventType);
}

public class Person implements ISource {

    private Set<IListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<IListener>();
    private String name;

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String _name) {

        name = _name;
        fireEvent(EventType.UPDATE);
    }

    public void addListener(IListener _listener) {

        listeners.add(_listener);
    }

    public void fireEvent(EventType _eventType) {

        // This line ok now (I just saw your edits)
        Event<? extends ISource> _event = new Event<Person>(this, _eventType);

        for(IListener listener : listeners) {

            listener.onEvent(_event);
        }
    }
}

// Problem here still - the type PersonListener must implement the inherited abstract method IListener.onEvent(Event<ISource>); I guess thats because of the following method...
public class PersonListener implements IListener {


    // Name clash: The method onEvent(Event<Person>) of type PersonListener has the
    // same erasure as onEvent(Event<? extends ISource>) of type IListener but does
    // not override it
    public void onEvent(Event<Person> _event) {

        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have several remarks:

- Why do you need `public class Source<ListenerType extends IListener<SourceType>, SourceType>`? Why does `Source` need to implement `IListener`? This seems unecessary complex.

I would do it in a slightly different way:

```
    public interface IListener {

    public void onEvent(Event<? extends ISource> _event);
    }
```

and

```
public interface ISource {
    public void addListener(IListener listener);
    public void fireEvent(EventType evenType)
}
```

I would implement Person and PersonListener as follows:

```
public class Person implement ISource {

private Collection<IListener> listeners;

private String name;

public String getName() { return name; }

public void setName(String _name) {

    name = _name;
    fireEvent(new Event<Person>(this, EventType.UPDATE));
}

public void addListener(IListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

public void fireEvent(EventType evenType) {
    Event<? extends ISource> _event = new Event<Person>(this, evenType);

    for(IListener listener : listeners) {

        listener.onEvent(_event);
    }
}

public Person(String _name) {

    setName(_name);
}
```

}

and:

```
public class PersonListener implements IListener {

public void onEvent(Event<? extends ISource> _event) {

    System.out.println("EVENT: " + _event.getSource().getName());
    // Would probably have a switch/case statement here to check the Event type (what happened?)
}
```

}

By not using Generics on Listener, you can decouple between the Observers and Observables.
For example, in your code, you can have PersonListener listen to other Sources as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input Amir. The Source does not implement IListener (i think?). It is given ListenerType as a generic, and that ListenerType extends IListener so that the Source can call the 'onEvent' method of the listener. Thats how I understand it at least. Your code looks much cleaner and I shall try it out now. I noticed the 'addListener' method is missing in your implementation of Person - would you suggest I keep copy/pasting that function into the different 'Source' classes I need (i.e Person, Driver, Dog, Cat)? Surely I'd be better off using inheritance to avoid dupe code?

Comment: I am thinking of a class called 'Source' again that implements ISource, that Person can subclass from (as can Driver, Dog, Cat etc). However that is probably going to introduce too much complexity again I guess?

Comment: I missed out on the Source - it does not implement IListener. Nevertheless, it is quite cumbersome. I should've added addListener to Person class. You can create an AbstractSource that implements these methods and other classes can inherit from it, but on the other hand, your classes can inherit from any other class, and just implement these 2 methods. That's up to you.

Comment: Ok I am in the midst of implementing your code and I see a problem - the IListener Interface appears to *need* a SourceType generic, else how does the argument in the onEvent method know what a SourceType is? You didnt specify it, but I dont see how that would work. Secondly I can see addListener in ISource is accepting an Interface as an argument? Now im more confused!

Comment: For your 2nd comment - you can have Person, Drivcer etc. inherit from Source, it's not a bad idea. But if you need to inherit from another class, you have the option of implementing ISource.

Comment: Thanks for your comments regarding the inheritance aspect using an Abstract class. That's what ill do - I think its a great idea.

Comment: My bad - I just learned you can indeed pass Interfaces as arguments you did in addListener - I truly thought that wouldnt work - I guess it does work because its not inside an implementation! Awesome. Still have the issue regarding the SourceType generic in the onEvent method of IListener. Thanks very much for your patience with my Java noobness :D

Comment: I would change public void onEvent(Event<SourceType> _event) in ILister to public void onEvent(Event<ISource> _event). This way the Listener is free to listen to events from all ISources, and is not bound to a single ISource, and will probably help with the compilation problem you mentioned before.

Comment: Genius :D Let me try that out now!

Comment: I changed the onEvent in IListener to take ISource. However I've got a couple of errors - 1. in fireEvent of Person, I have the line: Event<ISource> _event = new Event<Person>(this, _eventType); Im getting a type mismatch (cannot convert Event<ISource> to Event<Person>. If I change it to Event<Person> = new...; I get an error on the looped listener.onEvent(_event) line - the method onEvent(Event<Isource>) is not applicable for the args Event<Person>. 2 - In PersonListener I have public void onEvent(Event<Person> _event) - it tells me name-clash, same erasure as IListener, not overridding it.

Comment: Would it be easier for both of us (and others) if I edit the question and add the new code as I now have it? All these comments are messy and hard to read :)

Comment: Instead of public void onEvent(Event<SourceType> _event) you should use: public void onEvent(Event<? extends SourceType> _event)

Comment: Plz see my edits to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Amir, I was also updating my code at the same time as you :). Ive amended it here and in Eclipse and am left with just the error in PersonListener (name clash).

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot fix this 'type erasure' problem I am having within PersonListener. "Name clash: The method onEvent(Event<Person>) of type PersonListener has the same erasure as onEvent(Event<? extends ISource>) of type IListener but does not override it". I _sort of_ understand that Java sees this as a kind of duplicate method once the types have been erased but I have no idea how to solve it!

Comment: I can see your edit to the onEvent in PersonListener and this does seem like it would work. However, in doing that I am unable to determine the actual type 'Person' in that method. I.e I am unable to call _event.getSource().getName() (getName belongs to Person but not ISource). I have a horrible feeling casts are going to be needed, which is kinda what I hoped to avoid all along, else I'd just implement Java's own Observable/Observer classes :D